# how to find rows with a different column?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrix and say setl and setf with 4 column[X,Y,Z,Code] with different size. some of rows are same but some have a different Z,( same X, same Y and same Code). and some rows are completely different(different size).
How can I find the rows with the properties that say i.e. rows that have same X,Y and Code and different Z.
using ismember only give the same rows.and find need to 2 matrix with same size. expect to similar sizes by adding zeros to 2 matrix is another way?
Thanks.

Comment: `ismember(setl(:,[1,2,4]), setf(:,[1,2,4]), 'rows')`

Comment: have you look to function `find` ? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html